# I got this error when hit the delete icon on my react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_id')

this is my App.js file

```
function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(false);
    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        GetTodos();
    }, []);

    const GetTodos = () => {
        fetch(api_base + '/todos')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setTodos(data))
            .catch((err) => console.error("Error: ", err));
    }

    const completeTodo = async id => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + '/todo/complete/' + id).then(res => res.json());

        setTodos(todos => todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo._id === data._id) {
                todo.complete = data.complete;
            }

            return todo;
        }));
        
    }

    const deleteTodo = async id => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + '/todo/delete/' + id, { method: "DELETE" }).then(res => res.json());

        setTodos(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo._id !== data.result._id));
    }
```

Comment: `data.result` is `undefined` - are you sure the JSON has `result` property? (probably doesn't and that's the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have check the `result` key inside `data` response. You can check the below code for result key validation

```
const data = await fetch(api_base + '/todo/delete/' + id, { method: "DELETE" }).then(res => res.json());
if (data && data?.result?.__id) {
    setTodos(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo._id !== data.result._id))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the data must be getting undefined there, try to add a condition to check if data is present ,this is actually type error and you can fix this by checking if **data** and its properties are present continue with process this will prevent type errors

```
function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
    const [popupActive, setPopupActive] = useState(false);
    const [newTodo, setNewTodo] = useState("");

    useEffect(() => {
        GetTodos();
    }, []);

    const GetTodos = () => {
        fetch(api_base + '/todos')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => setTodos(data))
            .catch((err) => console.error("Error: ", err));
    }

    const completeTodo = async id => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + '/todo/complete/' + id).then(res => res.json());
if (data && data._id) {
        setTodos(todos => todos.map(todo => {
            if (todo._id === data._id) {
                todo.complete = data.complete;
            }

            return todo;
        }));
}
        
    }

    const deleteTodo = async id => {
        const data = await fetch(api_base + '/todo/delete/' + id, { method: "DELETE" }).then(res => res.json());
if (data && data.result && data.result._id) {
        setTodos(todos => todos.filter(todo => todo._id !== data.result._id));
}
    }
```

the function will trigger only if the data is present so you won't get any undefined error, copy paste this and try.I hope it works!!